# Can anyone explain how this loop manages to benchmark so high?

Tags: javascript, performance

http://jsperf.com/loops/67

If you look, the following loop manages some insane benchmarks:

```
var i=0;
var v;
for (i, v; v = arr[i++];) {
   v;
}
```

It score ~700 million ops/sec in FF, ~20 mil in Chrome, and ~50mil in IE10. The next fastest loop manages ~100k in FF, ~6k in IE10 and barely ~2k in Chrome.

Why is it so fast? I can see the obvious differences between the other loops and how one is faster than another, but I can't come up with anything that would explain the absolutely mind blowing performance difference with this loop, 700 million to 100k is an insane gap.

---

**Edit after answers:**

Based off @Michael Gary's answer, I went back and edited the setup to include an actual real array and the results fell back to reality: http://jsperf.com/loops/70

Comment: Since it isn't doing anything, it's probably been optimized as such by the interpreter.

Comment: Some sort of [Loop optimizations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_optimization) present in one and absent in the others?

Comment: on an assembler point of view this loop does just 3 things: move the array pointer one step to the right, test the new value,jump to loop beginning. this can be done quickly. no idea about javascript though. :(

Comment: Firefox might even assume "nothing is going on" and GG

Comment: The same can be said about all the other loops in the tests though, but yet this one scores spectacularly higher

Comment: @DarkLord7854, Who knows what tips off the interpreter that nothing is happening.  JavaScript can be tricky at times for what can be optimized, and what can't.

Comment: Why not: `for(i=0;v=arr[i++];)v;`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason is simple. The array `arr` is created with this code:

```
var arr = new Array(10000);
```

So it has a length of 10000, but all of the elements are `undefined`. This loop doesn't work off the array length, but terminates when it encounters a "falsy" value - the assumption being that the loop will stop when `v` receives an `undefined` value as a result of trying to read past the end of the array.

But in this particular array, all ten thousand elements have the value `undefined`. So the loop stops when it tests the very first element of the array. In other words, it doesn't loop at all! No wonder it's fast.

But what about a more real-world case? How does this kind of loop fare with a lengthy JSON array of objects:

```
[
    { "id": 507674, "name": "Kolink" },
    { "id": 997356, "name": "DarkLord7854" },
    { "id": 1202830, "name": "Michael Geary" },
    /* and thousands more */
]
```

Here you don't have the problem of the loop terminating immediately, since the array elements are all "truthy".

With modern JavaScript engines this turns out to be a fairly poor way to write a loop, as I recently found out to my extreme embarrassment.

I was one of the authors of the [jQuery Cookbook](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596159788.do): I wrote most of Chapter 5, "Faster, Simpler, More Fun". Well, the "faster" part didn't turn out so well. I was recommending a loop very much like yours for iterating over a large array of objects like the one above:

```
for( var item, i = -1;  item = array[++i]; ) {
    // do stuff with item
}
```

Turns out that in modern browsers, this is quite a bit slower than a conventional loop like this:

```
for( var i = 0, n = array.length;  i < n;  i++ ) {
    var item = array[i];
    // do stuff with item
}
```

Part of this is due to the fact that trying to read past the end of the array throws some JavaScript engines back into a deoptimized way of representing the array, as one of the V8 authors explained to me at Google I/O last year. Part of it may be due to the browsers optimizing the more common kinds of loops and not optimizing this less common approach.

Either way, the more conventional loop turns out to be faster in modern browsers:

http://jsperf.com/mikes-loops/2

But that's a different case from your loop. In yours, the insane performance increase is directly due to the fact that it doesn't run the loop *at all*. :-)

Comment: And that's what I get for being up late and not reading what the test was set up to do.. hah.

Thank you for the answer though, now I can go to sleep with my brain at ease

Comment: I went back and changed the setup to have a valid array, and you're completely correct: http://jsperf.com/loops/70

Answer (score 3):

`arr` is initialised to an array containing 10000 lots of bugger all. `Array(10000)` prepares the array's length, but does not populate it in any way.

Therefore, `arr[0]` will be `undefined`, which is falsy, so the for loop terminates immediately.

Essentially, the code boils down do:

```
var i=0;
var v;
i,v; // doesn't do anything but access the variables
v = undefined;
i++;
```

Comment: `undefined` instead of `null`